# What is the purpose of forbidding increment or decrement operators by eslint

Tags: javascript, increment, eslint, rules, decrement

The [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus) describes a way to forbid the increment and decrement operators `++` and `--`.

The description includes the sentence, that these operators

> are subject to automatic semicolon insertion, differences in whitespace can change semantics of source code.

By reading this, I still don't understand why it would be a good practice to forbid them. I could think of transpile or interpreter issues but I have no clear idea.

Also, I learned in nearly every tutorial, documentation and even at University courses to use these operators.

The following documentations also do not express concerns about them:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/increment-and-decrement-operators-javascript)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp)

I am very curious now what purpose it has to forbid their usage.

Comment: The page you link to shows an example of the problem. What about the example don't you understand? (Not that I think this is a useful rule. I happily use increment and decrement operators in my code. I also put semicolons where they're expected to be instead of relying on the horror of ASI.)

Comment: Read the section about it in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Comment: The quoted text in your question also explains the problem: "_differences in whitespace can change semantics of source code_".

Comment: Not every eslint rule automatically means "best practice", you need to understand this. Also to be fair their example of how whitespace can change semantics of the code, is very unrealistic (implied global in their code is far more common source of the problem).

Comment: Ok so when I get it right it is rather about the whitespace position before or after the operators in combination with a missing semicolon and ASI  than about the operators themselves!?